# Delete Magento database or site settings config?

Tags: magento-1.8, database, install, installation

I want to start my Magento installation from scratch. I'm unfamiliar with Magento, but in Drupal you can delete a settings.php and you db and it will be as if no Drupal has ever been installed. Then you can essentially go to the admin page and run setup like you do in the beginning.

Is there some file like this for Magento? If yes, please let me know the path to it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not.  You can delete app/etc/local.xml and then do the setup like new, but the old database will still be there and if you put in the info for that db connection your old data will be present with the new install.

Your best bet is to delete the old database and do a fresh install if you want to start from scratch.

Comment: That's what I did, delete the db. But if I delete local.xml then it sounds like it's the same thing as I was describing. Thanks.

Comment: I think so....but might as well delete the database so that data isn't sitting around if you don't need it.